# on() doesn't work as expected and does not work for newly loaded content

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, dynamic-data, content-script

My chrome extension is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    $("input[type!='password'], textarea").on("keypress", function (event) {
        ...
    });
});
```

This reacts as expected for the normally loaded content but does not work for inputs or textareas loaded later.

I though that was what on was supposed to do, am I using it wrong?

I've played around with something like this to try to solve it but with no success

```
$(doocument).on("keypress", "input[type!='password'], textarea"....
```

[Here is a live example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz7F5/3/), the first input works as expected, the generated ones don't.

Comment: Please reproduce that on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Did you even try that last selector you're suggesting -> [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yz7F5/4/)

Comment: @adeneo of course I did :) the thing is that I tried it in my script itself and fat fingered something... Sorry!

Comment: No problem, just funny to see someone posting the answer to their own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input[type!='password'], textarea", function (event) {
    alert("this works!");
});
```

The listener is being attached to the `document`, and any keypress events will be checked against `input[type!='password']` and `textarea`.

If your HTML markup was structured in a way that there was one parent container of `input[type!='password']` and `textarea`, you could replace `$(document)` with `$('.parent-container')` to only attach the listener on that element, as opposed to the entire document.

EDIT:
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yz7F5/5/